# memcpy columns of a 3D array into 1D array

Tags: c

I have a 3D array `mat` and I need to extract the first column and copy into an 1D array `arr`.

I have tried the below code where I can copy the first row of `mat` into `arr`, but I need to copy the first column of `mat` into `arr`. Is there any better way to do this without copying element by element?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int mat[4][2][4] = {{{1,2,3,4},{10,20,30,40}},{{11,12,13,14},{110,120,130,140}},{{21,22,23,24},{210,220,230,240}},{{31,32,33,34},{310,320,330,340}}};
int arr[4];
int index,idx;

for(index=0;index<4;index++){
    memcpy(arr, &mat[index][0], sizeof(arr));
    for(idx=0;idx<4;idx++){
        printf("%d\t",arr[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Actual results:

```
1   2   3   4   
11  12  13  14  
21  22  23  24  
31  32  33  34
```

Expected results:

```
1       10
11      110
21      210
31      310
```

*Updated

Comment: `for(idx=0;idx<4;idx++) printf("%d\t",arr[idx]);` this goes from `arr[0]` to `arr[3]`, yet `arr` is decalred to hold only two elements.

Comment: Worse, you are copying `sizeof(mat[0])` that is `sizeof(int[2][4]) = sizeof(int) * 8` bytes into `arr` which is only `int[2]`.

Comment: No way; The column values in the 3D-array are spread in memory, whereas the ones in the target 1D-array are next to each other; You'll have to map it "manually" in a loop.

Comment: `memcpy` is not the function to use for this. `memcpy` copies consecutive data but the data that you want is **not** consecutive. Consequently you can't use `memcpy`

Comment: Given `array[x][y][z]` C really doesn't care if you say that `x` is columns or `z` is columns, that's application-layer definitions beyond the language spec. C arrays only define a memory layout. The rule of thumb is that the right-most dimension (`z`) should be the one you access the most, as this gives faster code. Other than that, you are free use the array as you like.

Answer (score 3):

If I well understand you want that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int mat[4][2][4] = {{{1,2,3,4},{10,20,30,40}},{{11,12,13,14},{110,120,130,140}},{{21,22,23,24},{210,220,230,240}},{{31,32,33,34},{310,320,330,340}}};
  int arr[2];
  int index,idx;

  for (index=0; index<4; ++index) {
    /* only set */
    for (idx=0; idx<2; ++idx) {
      arr[idx] = mat[index][idx][0];
    }

    /* only print */
    for (idx=0; idx<2; ++idx) {
      printf("%d\t", arr[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Execution produces :

```
1   10  
11  110 
21  210 
31  310
```

I separated on purpose the assignment and the print loops even they are the same

---

But it is strange to only use the index 0 for the last dimension, so I think in fact you want that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int mat[4][2][4] = {{{1,2,3,4},{10,20,30,40}},{{11,12,13,14},{110,120,130,140}},{{21,22,23,24},{210,220,230,240}},{{31,32,33,34},{310,320,330,340}}};
  int arr[2];
  int idx0, idx1, idx2;

  for (idx2 = 0; idx2 != 4; ++idx2) {
    for (idx0=0; idx0<4; ++idx0) {
      /* only set */
      for (idx1=0;idx1<2;idx1++) {
        arr[idx1] = mat[idx0][idx1][idx2];
      }

      /* only print */
      for (idx1=0;idx1<2;idx1++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[idx1]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The execution produces :

```
1   10  
11  110 
21  210 
31  310 
2   20  
12  120 
22  220 
32  320 
3   30  
13  130 
23  230 
33  330 
4   40  
14  140 
24  240 
34  340
```

Comment: I need the output from your first execution, but you are copying the elements 1 by 1. For 2 rows, this is not bad but when I have 1000+ rows I have to manually copy each element. I am looking for an alternative approach for fast copy operation.

Comment: As it was said in remarks you need to get non consecutive values, so you have to get them separately

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use memcpy, the data must be consecutive. I am going to try to explain it with the following code.

First part : I use your matrix to show you the data order in memory.

Second part : I reorder datas (Rq : For testing and understanding purpose, I think, it would be best to have different number of element for each dimension. Ex [3][2][4] to avoid some confusion. Nevertheless, I do not change it to keep your data)

Third part : I use memcpy as you did.

I have a question. Are you trying to adapt some code from fortran to C ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
//First part
int mat[4][2][4]={{{1,2,3,4},{10,20,30,40}},{{11,12,13,14},{110,120,130,140}},{{21,22,23,24},{210,220,230,240}},{{31,32,33,34},{310,320,330,340}}};
int *ptr=mat;
int i=0;
for (int z=0; z<4; z++) for (int y=0; y<2; y++) for (int x=0; x<4; x++) printf("mat(%d,%d,%d)=%d\n",x,y,z,ptr[i++]);

printf("\n------------------------\n\n");

//Second part
/* int mat[4][2][4]=
    {{{1,2,3,4},            {10,20,30,40}},
    {{11,12,13,14},         {110,120,130,140}},
    {{21,22,23,24},         {210,220,230,240}},
    {{31,32,33,34},         {310,320,330,340}}}; */
// Written like that to show "a sort of matrix transposition" (do not take this words mathematically)of left and right part.

int mat1[4][2][4]={
    {{1,11,21,31},          {10,110,210,310}},
    {{2,12,22,32},          {20,120,220,320}},
    {{3,13,23,33},          {30,130,230,330}},
    {{4,14,24,34},          {40,140,230,340}}
};

int *ptr1=mat1;
i=0;
for (int z=0; z<4; z++) for (int y=0; y<2; y++) for (int x=0; x<4; x++) printf("mat(%d,%d,%d)=%d\n",x,y,z,ptr1[i++]);

//Third part
int arr[4];
int index,idx;

for(index=0;index<2;index++){
    memcpy(arr, &mat1[0][index], sizeof(arr));
    for(idx=0;idx<4;idx++){
        printf("%d\t",arr[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```